# UITraitCollectionの使い方について

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

現在`UITraitCollection`を使ってiPhoneとiPadを区別しようとしているのですが、イマイチ`UITraitCollection`の使い方がわかりません。
まず以下のようにコードを書いてデバイスの回転時にRegularかCompactかを検知してそれに沿った処理を記述するようにしました。

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    if (newCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) {
        NSLog(@"Regular");

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        ViewController *VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC];
        [self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:navVC sender:self];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Compact");

    }
    [super willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

しかし上記のコードだとiPhone 6plusを縦画面から横画面にした時にアプリが落ちます。無限ループのような形で落ちます。なぜアプリが落ちてしまうのでしょうか？
また、showDetailViewControllerに関するロジックを除けてログだけを取るようにすると、なぜか画面を一回転させただけでも、「Compact Regular Compact」というようにログに表示されます。
そして、`viewDidLoad`で下記のコードをiPadで実行すると、「Regular Compact」とログが表示されます。

```
if ([self.traitCollection containsTraitsInCollection: [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular]]) {
    NSLog(@"Regular");

} else {
    NSLog(@"Compact") 
}
```

なぜ二回も呼ばれているのか調べると、`willTransitionToTraitCollection`が呼ばれていたようです。画面が回転してないにもかかわらず。
このように、全くUITraitCollectionを使用してiPhoneとiPadを区別することができてません。
なぜ上記のような複数回メソッドが呼ばれたり、アプリが無限ループになって落ちたりする挙動になってしまっているのでしょうか？
色々と調べてみても`UITraitCollection`の具体的な使い方に関する記事が少なく、これ以上どうすればいいかわかりません。
どなたかわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問が多数含まれているので、順番に解答します。

また、質問に必要な情報が含まれていないので、以下の仮定の下に解答をしています。

- Master-Detail Applicationのひな形からプロジェクトを作成
- 質問文にあるwillTransitionToTraitCollectionはMasterViewControllerに追加

### iPhone 6 Plusを回転したときに落ちる

willTransitionToTraitCollectionの中でshowDetailViewControllerを呼び出しているのが原因です。

showDetailViewControllerを呼び出した結果、UISplitViewControllerにwillTransitionToTraitCollectionが発生し、UISplitViewControllerに管理されているMasterViewControllerにもそれが派生するので無限ループになっているようです。

無限ループになった結果、最終的にスタックオーバーフローでアプリが落ちます。

### iPhone 6 Plusを回転したときに『Compact Regular Compact』と表示される

おそらく、UISplitViewControllerの仕様（副作用？）だと思われます。

UISplitViewControllerを使っていないプロジェクトであれば、回転後のTraitに合わせて、willTransitionToTraitCollectionは1回しか呼び出されません。

1回目のCompactは謎です。2回目のRegularはiPhone 6 Plusを横にした結果。3回目のCompactはUISplitViewControllerでMasterViewControllerが狭まった結果のように思えます。

### iPadで実行すると『Regular Compact』と表示される

これも、UISplitViewControllerの仕様だと思われます。

viewDidLoadとwillTransitionToTraitCollectionで同じ単語を出力しているのでわかりにくいですが、1回目のRegularはviewDidLoadに追加されたコードによる出力で、2回目のCompactはwillTransitionToTraitCollectionによるものです。

画面を回転させていないのに、willTransitionToTraitCollectionからCompactが出力される理由ですが、おそらく、UISplitViewControllerがDetailViewControllerを表示した結果だと思われます。

### iPhoneとiPadを区別する方法

UIDeviceのcurrentDeviceを使えば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。iPhoneを回転させた時にはMasterViewControllerにもwillTransitionToTraitCollectionするから無限ループに陥っていたのですね。なるほど。。。
「CompactやRegular」の識別がおかしかいと感じたのはSplitViewControllerの仕様なのですね。こういう仕様のことはどこにも注意点として書かれてなかったのでかなりハマってしまいました...。
そうですね、素直にUIDeviceのcurrentDeviceを使おうと思います。UITraitCollectionを使うことになぜが固執していました。
この度は丁寧に解説してくださりありがとうございました。疑問が解決できました。